# Regex extension and language

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I looking into validating some file names. But cant figure out correct regex
file names can be anything, but need to check if filename ends with

1. _ underscore
2. en or ru or cy (country code 2 letters)
3. . (dot)
4. extensions (jpeg, jpg, mp4, png, gif)

so file

```
my_file_dummy_name.jpeg - not valid
my_file_dummy_name_en.jpeg - valid
```

For Now I tried this (and is working but maybe there is better solution)

```
/(\_\w.\.\w+)/g
```

One more:

```
/(\_[a-z]{2}\.[a-z]{3,4})/g
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with your original regex is that, while it would match the filenames you want to allow, it would also match things you don't want.

For example, the following regex

```
/(\_\w{2}\.\w+)/g
```

would match the file `my_file_dummy_name_de.mpeg`, which is a video file from Germany.  Clearly, we wouldn't want to watch this in the first place.

Try this regex:

```
_(en|ru|cy)\.(jpeg|jpg|mp4|png|gif)$
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: Certainly, this can be improved a bit: `/_(?:en|ru|cy)\.(?:jpe?g|mp4|png|gif)$/`, but it depends what one seeks in regex :)

Comment: Damn, I was typing on mobile during commute hahah

Comment: @rgoliveira Guess what...I'm also on mobile, though it usually ends badly for me.  Upvote coming at you.

Comment: @Mariano It is much easier on Android than iOS in my opinion.  I have even done SQL Fiddles on mobile.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the regex to do all the checking for you, there's a more strict way to go about this:

```
/_(en|ru|cy)\.(jpeg|jpg|mp4|png|gif)$/
```

This way you ensure all those constraints you mentioned. Also, there's no need for the `g`lobal flag, as we're only interested in the end of the string (this is why I put the EOL anchor `$`). You could add, though, the `i`gnore case flag if there's a possibility of mixed case in the filenames.